# Which is better: A single delegate for multiple events vs multiple delegates for multiple events?

Tags: events, delegates

I'm curious if a single delegate to manage a large number of events is better than using multiple delegates to handle all those events.

For instance, lets say I have 50 events all under the same "category" and class. There are 5 groups those events could be organized into. Would you just make 1 delegate for all 50 related events, or make 5 delegates for the specific groups of 10 events each?

Edit: This may sound like an obvious question, but I don't have a strong enough understanding to confidently answer this for myself.

Edit2: Here is some example code.

```
    //## Left-Button
public delegate void LeftButtonHandler();
public static event LeftButtonHandler LeftButtonHeldEvent;
public static event LeftButtonHandler LeftButtonUpEvent;
private static void LeftButton(){
    if (Input.GetButton("KeyLeft")){
        if (LeftButtonHeldEvent != null)
            LeftButtonHeldEvent();
    }
}
private static void LeftButtonUp(){
    if(Input.GetButtonUp("KeyLeft")){
        if (LeftButtonUpEvent != null)
            LeftButtonUpEvent();
    }
}

//## Down-Button
public delegate void DownButtonHandler();
public static event DownButtonHandler DownButtonHeldEvent;
public static event DownButtonHandler DownButtonUpEvent;
private static void DownButton(){
    if (Input.GetButton("KeyDown")){
        if (DownButtonHeldEvent != null)
            DownButtonHeldEvent();
    }
}
private static void DownButtonUp() {
    if (Input.GetButtonUp("KeyDown")) {
        if (DownButtonHeldEvent != null)
            DownButtonUpEvent();
    }
}
```

The question is regarding this, I have MANY more inputs that I am polling. Is it better to just make 1 delegate for all the keys, than to use a new delegate for each key?

Note: This is in unity, but this is not a unity specific question. I understand input polling to publish events is a bit absurd, but unity does not provide a way to subscribe to their own UI events. I am not particularly concerned about that at this time, only about whether I should use 1 delegate or multiple delegates.

Comment: I would absolutely hate to have to maintain a codebase that has 50 different delegates that all do the same thing. Hate it to the point that if a prospective employer revealed that to me in an interview and subsequently made me an offer I would probably turn them down.

Comment: That said, I would probably hate a single delegate with a switch statement containing >5 cases even more... see, this is why it'd be helpful for you to post some code to give an example of the situation you are facing. There's not really a 100% bulletproof answer here.

Comment: So would you say, for the example given, a single delegate would be best? I am just making sure sing the answer appears to be so obvious I'm questioning whether I really know it or not.

Edit: gotcha, I'll put some code in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example I would have one handler that takes a parameter containing the value of the key pressed/held, e.g.:

```
public delegate void ButtonHandler(object sender, string whichButton);
public static event ButtonHandler ButtonHeldEvent;
public static event ButtonHandler ButtonUpEvent;

private static void ButtonHeld()
{
  string keyHeld = "..."; //Todo: Code to get which button is being held
  if (ButtonHeldEvent != null)
  {
     ButtonHeldEvent(this, keyHeld);
  }
}

private static void ButtonUp()
{
  string keyUp = "..."; //Todo: Code to get which button is up
  if (ButtonUpEvent != null)
  {
    ButtonUpEvent(this, keyUp);
  }
}
```

Let the subscribers to the event figure out what to do if it's KeyLeft, KeyDown, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, instead of having an event for each keypress, I'd have the subscribed event handler figure it out via if/else or switches. And ultimately a single delegate will work in the end.